# jersey-freemarker not resolving templates

Tags: jersey, jetty, classpath, freemarker

I am trying to create a simple [jersey-freemarker](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/contribs/jersey-freemarker) webapp, which I'm running with the jetty-maven-plugin.
But the `FreemarkerViewProcessor` won't find my templates.

I have created a jersey resource at `@Path("/")` with a `@GET public Viewable getIndex()` method, that gets invoked once I request `http://localhost:8080/`.
This `Viewable` is set to use the `"index"` template.

Assume the resource is `com.example.MainResource` (located in `src/main/java/com/example/MainResource.java`), and the `index.ftl` template file is located in `src/main/webapp/templates/com/example/MainResource/index.ftl`.

In my servlet setup, I tell jersey-freemarker about the `templates` directory, using a configuration `Map`: `config.put(FreemarkerViewProcessor.FREEMARKER_TEMPLATES_BASE_PATH, "templates");`.
When debugging the [`FreemarkerViewProcessor`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/contribs/jersey-freemarker/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/freemarker/FreemarkerViewProcessor.java#L103), I see that it is indeed looking for the template resource based on the path `/templates/com/example/MainResource/index.ftl`.

**Where should I put my template files so the `FreemarkerViewProcessor` will find them? Or how do I include my `templates` directory in the classpath?**

PS: `mvn jetty:run` produces the following output (in part):

```
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: jettytest-servlet
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src/main/webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = ~/jettytest-servlet/target/classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = ~/jettytest-servlet/target/tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:~/jettytest-servlet/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = ~/jettytest-servlet/src/main/webapp
```

Update:
The `FreemarkerViewProcessor` always uses a default [`Configuration`](https://github.com/freemarker/freemarker/blob/2.3-gae/src/main/java/freemarker/template/Configuration.java), which sais to use a class-loader based template loader.
As per [@ddekany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606679/ddekany)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500535/jersey-freemarker-not-resolving-templates?noredirect=1#comment34265585_22500535), I should therefore place my `templates/` in `WEB-INF/classes/`. To me that feels dirty; it seems like this should be taken care of by Maven.

Because of the `FreemarkerViewProcessor`'s design (always using a class-loader configuration), I have posted [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22534429/1296709). In the meantime, suggestions telling me how I can add the `src/main/webapp/` directory to the classpath are welcome as well.

Comment: FreeMarker works with a virtual filesystem implemented by a `TemplateLoader` object. So you should check what kind of `TemplateLoader` is used there. Like if it's class-loader based, then certainly you should put the templates under `WEB-INF/classes/templates/...`. Another often used location is `WEB-INF/templates/...`.

Comment: I have updated the question, and it seems like the `jersey-freemaker` implementation has some limitations. But I don't know how to overcome those yet.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22554915/1296709), using my own `FreemarkerViewProcessor` is not that difficult. So I copied the jersey-freemarker implementation and adapted it to use a Guice-injected `Configuration` object that I bind in my `ServletModule`.

Now I don't need the jersey-freemarker module any more, *and* I can skip putting stuff in the servlet config `Map` for freemarker.