# Install custom Jersey ViewProcessor from Guice ServletModule

Tags: jersey, guice, guice-servlet

I am using [jersey-guice](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-guice/1.18.1) to set up all my Jersey 1 resources using a bunch of Guice (Servlet)Modules.

I have written a custom [`ViewProcessor`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/jersey-server/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/spi/template/ViewProcessor.java) (`CustomViewProcessor`) that relies on a configuration object, that I want to be injected into it using Guice. This `CustomViewProcessor` *should* be picked up and used by Jersey every time it needs one.

**How do I tell Jersey to fetch a Guice-created `CustomViewProcessor` instance whenever it needs a `ViewProcessor`?** I want to set all this up within my Guice `Module`s' `configure` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is rather easy: Just create that `CustomViewProcessor` class and annotate it with [`@Provider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html). By `bind`ing it with Guice (and having jersey-guice installed), your `CustomViewProcessor` will be instantiated and used in the right places.

The `CustomViewProcessor` class can use all the `@Inject`ed fields that you wish, like configuration objects.